# Get the device's real display size/DPI

Tags: javascript, html

Is there some way to get the real screen-size or DPI of the device? I have certain elements in my application which are not usable if the display is too small and need to switch to a different presentation and/or omit the elements.

Comment: I believe the usual approach involves [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#resolution) in your CSS.

Comment: It can't be CSS, I need to know from JavaScript in order to alter the DOM.

Comment: `window.devicePixelRatio` then, even though IIRC it's kind of insane: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/06/devicepixelrati.html, http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/07/more_about_devi.html. `screen.width` is either in physical pixels or dips, depending on device. See also: http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport.html. I'd consider looking for a virgin or a goat.

Comment: @millimoose that shows the relation between logical and device pixels, there's no way to determine the actual size of the device from that.

Comment: No. It does however tell you how many UI elements of a given size you can fit on the screen, as well as estimate what physical size an element of a given pixel size will be. I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish, or what you mean by "too small" where a size in dips won't help. (A dip, if I understand it correctly, is meant to be a fuzzy physical "unit" – a dot approximately the size of a common "non-retina" LCD display pixel, so give or take 1/96 of an inch.)

Comment: No, it doesn't help determine phyiscal size. If a screen is 600, 1200, or 2400 real pixesl doesn't say how big they are. I have the problem that some of my visual elements are not usable at a small tablet size. They can't be made larger, but will simply be omitted.

Comment: My point is that, say, an iPhone screen should **always** be 320dips across, regardless of pixel density. And, in fact, the iPhone browser will give you dips when you ask for pixels. Now, if Apple releases a browser with a wider screen, it's possible they'll increase its width, or keep it the same and make their dips *slightly* larger, but that shouldn't negatively impact readability.

Comment: The one outlier would be the iPad mini screen, where UI elements would in fact be notably smaller than on the full-sized iPad at the same dip dimensions. That said I believe the idea is that you should use the same pixel dimensions for UI elements between the iPhone and the iPad. That means a button will be the same physical size on the iPhone and the iPad Mini, and larger on the full-size iPad. (I.e.: you're not supposed to cram more content on an iPad by using smaller UI elements and fonts just because the larger pixel size will make them usable.)

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** No. [There's (currently) no way to accurately design for the web using physical units](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/21/responsive-web-design-with-physical-units/).

**Longer answer:** you can only try to rely on the size of a "CSS Pixel" being *roughly* the same between devices, since device manufacturers have a vested interest in preserving the usability of sites when they have "high" pixel densities (~> 90 dpi).

A couple of notable exceptions:

- the iPad mini is the same resolution as the original iPad, but (obviously) much smaller.
- Opera on Android offers to pretend to be a desktop browser, including a fake device-width, etc...

Comment: This is basically what millimoose is saying in the question comment. Hardware pixels are different to css pixels (aka dips). Make sure you're using a `viewport` `meta` tag to request the `width=device-width`, and try hard to find the right set of compromises... ;/

Comment: This is wrong for two reasons. In front of me I have a desktop and tablet with about the same resolution, yet the tablet has about 1/5th of the screen area. Two tablets sitting side by side, one has half the screen size, but nearly the same pixel resolution.  Secondly, I'm not asking about CSS pixels, I'm requesting this information from JavaScript.

Comment: Yes: devices differ in resolution and density. However, for most modern ("high density") devices, a hardware pixel is almost a private "implementation detail" of the device. Website authors (with CSS _and_ Javascript) deal with "CSS pixels", which is a layer that has been inserted to allow website authors to continue to talk about "1 pixel" and have it automatically map to 1, 2, 0.73, or 3.62 _hardware_ pixels, depending on the density of the device (and the "pinch" magnificiation level, if in effect). Unfortunately, this can't ever translate to a size in _real_ units (inches).

Comment: You _can_ translate pixels into real dimensions if you are willing to stoop to User Agent sniffing to determine the device, and to maintain a database of "scale factors" with which to convert pixels to real units. (If this is a reasonable solution for you, be careful that you fully understand how problematic this would be!)

Comment: (I added a smashing link to cite that physical units are currently inaccessible to web authors.)